# how to add google translate on goldendict?

Tags: dictionary, translation, google-translate

how to add google translate on goldendict
I use GldenDict as offline dictionary and sometimes can be online when 
 i want to add google translate into GoldenDict. Can you give me a hand? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the sources tab, select websites and add this:

Español-Inglés: http://translate.google.com/translate_t#en|es|%GDISO1%
Inglés-Español: http://translate.google.com/translate_t#en|es|%GDWORD%

Comment: Due to changes in the layout by Google this method does not work currently. See [here](https://github.com/goldendict/goldendict/issues/106) for more information.

Comment: here is an other solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49972190/how-to-simply-implement-online-dictionaries-for-goldendict/